# Can You help me simplify ~Q ∧ (P→Q) ∧ (R ∨ ~Q)?

Tags: propositional-calculus

can you help me solving this problem, I got stucked answering it in the beginning and hoping that you can help me with this. Thanks!

~Q ∧ (P→Q) ∧ (R ∨ ~Q)

Comment: $\lnot Q \land (P \rightarrow Q)$ is equivalent to $\lnot P$. Also $\lnot Q \land (R \lor \lnot Q)$ is equivalent to $\lnot Q$. You are hence left with $\lnot P$.

Comment: What means "simplification"? DNF? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) Another thing?

Comment: @Bermudes $\neg Q\wedge(P\rightarrow Q)$ is not equivalent to $\neg P$, it just implies $\neg P$. Hence, we are not "left" with only $\neg P$.

Answer (score 1):

If we go by truth table as follows:

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
P &Q &R &\neg Q &P\rightarrow Q &R\vee \neg Q & \neg Q \wedge (P\rightarrow Q) \wedge (R\vee \neg Q) \\
\hline
T &T &T &F &T &T &F \\
\hline
T &T &F &F &T &F &F  \\
\hline
T &F &T &T &F &T &F  \\
\hline
T &F &F &T &F &T &F  \\
\hline
F &T &T &F &T &T &F  \\
\hline
F &T &F &F &T &F &F  \\
\hline
F &F &T &T &T &T &T  \\
\hline
F &F &F &T &T &T &T  \\
\hline
\end{array}

Note that, in the last column, only the last two entries are true. By looking at the corresponding entries of P, Q, and R, it does not matter what value R is taking (P and Q should both take value false). Therefore, the simplified value is $\neg$ P $\wedge \neg$ Q.

Answer (score 0):

```
~Q ∧ (P→Q) ∧ (R ∨ ~Q)
   = ~Q ∧ (~P ∨ Q) ∧ (R ∨ ~Q)
   = ((~Q ∧ ~P) ∨ (~Q ∧ Q)) ∧ (R ∨ ~Q)
   = ((~Q ∧ ~P) ∨ FALSE) ∧ (R ∨ ~Q)
   = (~Q ∧ ~P) ∧ (R ∨ ~Q)
   = (~Q ∧ ~P ∧ R) ∨ (~Q ∧ ~P ∧ ~Q)
   = (~Q ∧ ~P ∧ R) ∨ (~Q ∧ ~P)
   = (~Q ∧ ~P ∧ R) ∨ (~Q ∧ ~P ∧ TRUE)
   = (~Q ∧ ~P) ∧ (R ∨ TRUE)
   = (~Q ∧ ~P) ∧ TRUE
   = (~Q ∧ ~P)
```